# line integral (multivariable calculus)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

Evaluate the line integral

$$
\int_C (\ln y) e^{-x} \,dx - \dfrac{e^{-x}}{y}\,dy + z\,dz
$$

where C is the curve parametrized by $r(t)=(t-1)i+e^{t^4}j+(t^2+1)k$ for $0\leq t\leq 1$

Answer (score 2):

[By my previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1041305/76987), the vector field:
$$
\vec F = \left\langle e^{-x} \ln y, \frac{-e^{-x}}{y}, z \right\rangle
$$
is conservative. Thus, the exact path of integration is irrelevant and we only care about the endpoints. Simply use the potential function from my previous answer and apply the [Fundamental Theorem for Line Integrals](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/FundThmLineIntegrals.aspx).